# Google Voice will not activate my mobile, goes straight to VMail?

Tags: google-voice

I have Google Voice and have had trouble since going from T-Mobile to Verizon.  I tried to delete and re-enter my mobile number in Google Voice, but now I cannot even activate the number. When Google calls to activate, it goes straight to Verizon Voice Mail and never rings.  Other callers do not have this issue.

How can I get Google Voice reactivated on my Verizon mobile number?